# 'ChargeCreateOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SourceId'

Tags: stripe-payments

I use Stripe v27. When I add option to ChargeCreateOptions, its have a error:

> 'ChargeCreateOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SourceId'

This is my code snippet:

```
public IActionResult Processing(StripePaymentRequest paymentRequest)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Metadata.Add("Product", "RubberDuck");
        Metadata.Add("Quantity", "10");
        var options = new ChargeCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = 100,
            Currency = "USD",
            Description = "Buying 10 rubber ducks",
            SourceId = paymentRequest.tokenId,
            Metadata = Metadata
        };
        var service = new ChargeService();
        Charge charge = service.Create(options);
        return Json(charge);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the library's [source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/StripeTests/Infrastructure/Public/StripeClientTest.cs#L24-L29) [code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/Charges/ChargeCreateOptions.cs#L104), `SourceId` became `Source` in v27. Try `Source = paymentRequest.tokenId` instead of `SourceId`

```
    var options = new ChargeCreateOptions
    {
        Amount = 123,
        Currency = "usd",
        Source = "tok_visa",
    };
```